# How to extend Configurable Class with session data

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, blocks, extensions, session

I'm trying to extend the class `\Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable` to access session data.
So I did this as proposed on so many stacks and tutorials.

```
class ExtendConfigurable extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,
        EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        Data $helper,
        CatalogProduct $catalogProduct,
        CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        ConfigurableAttributeData $configurableAttributeData,
        SwatchData $swatchHelper,
        Media $swatchMediaHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $arrayUtils, $jsonEncoder, $helper, $catalogProduct, $currentCustomer, $priceCurrency, $configurableAttributeData, $swatchHelper, $swatchMediaHelper, $data);
    }
```

This works. So now I want to inject the session data:

```
class ExtendConfigurable extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,
        EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        Data $helper,
        CatalogProduct $catalogProduct,
        CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        ConfigurableAttributeData $configurableAttributeData,
        SwatchData $swatchHelper,
        Media $swatchMediaHelper,
        array $data = [],
        Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $arrayUtils, $jsonEncoder, $helper, $catalogProduct, $currentCustomer, $priceCurrency, $configurableAttributeData, $swatchHelper, $swatchMediaHelper, $data);
        $this->customerSession = $session
    }
```

But all I get is:

> must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\Session, none given

How can I extend that class to access session data?

Answer (score 0):

Can't confirm with this special case (getting session data) just yet.
But in another case what was needed is recompiling di.

`bin/magento setup:di:compile`